# How Can I Enable a Multi-Lingual Catalog Block on Drupal 6.32 + Ubercart 6.x-2.13

Tags: ubercart, i18n-l10n, ajax

### Description of Problem

No matter what I try, I cannot get my Ubercart Catalog Block to change languages when I use the Language Switcher.  You can test this behaviour for yourself at:

**holistichorsecare.com/zh/products/aromadog-arf-ritis-pain-relief-1oz**

Regardless of the language context (English or Chinese, "en" or "zh-hant"), the shopping cart block on the left margin of the page, under all circumstances, displays this text:

**Shopping cart**

**There are no products in your shopping cart.**

**0 Items   Total: HK$ 0.00**

Go ahead and give it a try.  Load the page and click on English or Chinese as they appear in the page header.  The shopping cart block does not change languages- and I'd like it to.

### The Localization Files are Installed - I Think...

I've installed the following localization strings packages using the Administration front end and they appeared to be loaded correctly.

- ubercart-6.x-2.13.zh-hant.po
- uc_ajax_cart-6.x-1.0.zh-hant.po

### Checking out the Module Code

Looking into:

holistichorsecare.com/www/content/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart/translations/zh-hant

I see the following entry around line 1926:

msgid "There are no products in your shopping cart."
msgstr "ä½ (å¦³)ç
                 è³¼ç©è»è£¡æ²æä»»ä½åå."

(the garbled text is the multi-byte characters breaking up in my shell)

Looking into

holistichorsecare.com/www/content/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart/cart.module

I see the following call around line 706:

```
$output = '<p class="uc-cart-empty">'. t('There are no products in your shopping cart.') .'</p>';
```

So it appears that there is a call to t() to translate the string, but none is forthcoming from whatever system there is that serves up the alternatives.

Can someone please tell me where I need to go in the administration front end to enable localization/translation for the shopping cart block (ajax cart) in Ubercart?

I'm thinking I just missed a check box somewhere to turn on the translation, or have to tell Drupal/Ubercart that the strings in the Shopping Cart Block are to be translated, but I don't know where to go or how to do this.

P.S.:  When I called i18n_get_lang() in troubleshooting code I got the right answer back (i.e. "en" or "zh-hant"), so the system knows what language context it is in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you CAN NOT HAVE Ubercart multilingual because the project was started on the wrong way and now the developer team have no interest/possibility/capability to rewrite a lot of code!

Comment: Hello,

I paid a developer to make Ubercart multi-lingual aware.  

It took a month, was affordable and it works great now.

Take a look:  www.holistichorsecare.com